# Azure Mobile App, Cordova client, Azure AD - refresh tokens?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

This stack is shaping up to be perfect for our use case:

- Azure Mobile App
- Azure AD
- C# backend (using `GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>()` to authorize users to API endpoints based on security group membership)
- Cordova client

The missing piece of the puzzle for me is the ability to silently obtain a refresh token. Can the Token Store take care of this for me? Or is there a supported method of doing this either with the Cordova plugin, or in the C# backend?

I mean, the inappbrowser caches credentials, so it's not like the users have to type a password again, but still, the window pops up and it would look a bit more polished if it was silent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a little more tricky for Azure AD compared to the other providers. As a starter, I recommend you check out this blog post: http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/

It describes how to set up your mobile app backend to allow it to access the graph API on behalf of the user. Specifically, the following steps are required:

> - Set **clientSecret** (a string property) to the key value that was
>     generated in the Azure AD portal.
> - Set **additionalLoginParams** to the
>     following: (This is a JSON array value)

```
["response_type=code id_token", "resource=https://graph.windows.net"]
```

I assume this might be useful for your app anyways since you're checking security group memberships? If you'd rather not do that, then you can remove the "resource=https://graph.windows.net" parameter.

In any case, as a side effect of following these instructions, you will start receiving refresh tokens for each logged-in user, which you can use to support silent token refresh in your Cordova client.

Comment: Hi Chris, I followed your articles with the above settings, and through Azure Mobile App for Cordova plugin js file and try to refresh by this code: 

mobileService.invokeApi("/.auth/refresh", { method: "GET"})

but it always return "Not Found". 
Could you shed some light on it?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, it always return "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Resolved. Since mobileService.invokeApi("/.auth/refresh", { method: "GET"})  will construct the url https://xxxx.azurewebsite.net/api/.auth/refresh, which is wrong, we shouldn't use invokeApi. The correct url shouldn't contain "api". So instead, we change code to mobileService._request("GET", "/.auth/refresh", null, null, { accept: "application/json", "ZUMO-API-VERSION": "2.0.0" }, [], (error, response) => { alert(response.responseText);});   Then everything goes well.